# Do you use repositories in Doctrine2 and Symfony2?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, symfony, soa

I'm trying to find the best way to design my application and precisely my domain model.

I took a look at most of FOS*Bundle and they abstract the things like this :

```
Model/
- AbstractUser.php
- AbstractUserManager.php
Entity/
- User.php
- UserManager.php
```

They don't use Repository at all and all the work is done in the Manager classes.

I used to do something similar but in a different fashion.

I didn't abstract the domain model with abstract and interface (well it looks that it is definitely the way to go) but I had only Entities (the main goal of FOS is to be storage agnostic and allow the use of ODM or ORM).

So I've such structure:

```
Model/
- Entity/
-- User.php
- Repository/
-- UserRepository.php
Service/
- UserService.php
```

You bet it, the `UserService` is similar to the `UserManager` in FOS but it is mostly a Proxy class to the `UserRepository`.

What do you think?

How do you organize your domain model, do you have any feedback?

Do the FOS fashion the way to go?

Comment: I agree with you but sometimes answers, while valuable, are not the excepted answer to be the accepted one, letting them in that state allow other people to keep answering or resurrecting a question which didn't have an accepted answer. By the way, I though that people help, to help, not to be awarded by some score, but I may be utopic :) note that I ever upvote valuable answer however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my bundles, i normally use this method:

Entity/

- User.php

Repository/

- UserRepository.php

Service/

- UserService.php

Comment: Can you go deeply in how you manage your service with your repository? Are the repositories injected in your service or the entity manager?